# How i can use useContext hook or just a Context in a middleware in the React-Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, react-context

I had faced with a problem. The problem: I had tried to use context inside a middleware, but i`dont know how i can do it, because we can use useContext only in... *'Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.* **Is it possible to use context inside the middleware?** Thx for help!

'I have a context:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const PopupContext = createContext();

export const PopupContextProvider = (props) => {

  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);

  return (<PopupContext.Provider
    value={[isShow, setIsShow]}
  >
    {props.children}
  </PopupContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { PopupContextProvider } from './context/popup/popup';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PopupContextProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </PopupContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and my store.js - it`s a Redux store, you know...

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import alertMiddleware from '../middleware/alert.middleware';
import authReducer from './features/auth/auth-slice';
import cardReducer from './features/card/cardSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    card: cardReducer
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(alertMiddleware)
})

export default store;
```

and my dumb middleware

```
import { PopupContext } from '../context/popup/popup';
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';

const alertMiddleware = store => next => action => {

  const isShow = useContext(PopupContext);

  if (action.type === 'auth/login/rejected') {
    console.log(isShow);
  }

  console.log('middleware');
  next(action)
}

export default alertMiddleware;
```

Comment: Why not move the popup context into redux? The infrastructure for handling state across components is already there. The fact that your redux middleware needs to know about this state also suggests it should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, like i had understood, it's imposible to use context in your middleware (so sad). In this way, i had created a slice with reducers and etc. And now, a can take out all my logic in reducers, if someone doesn't know what is it... well, it's like a global state with services, which are available from all points in your application. The logic is: when some action type happen, the middleware handles it and dispatches some actions, in this action you can do everething, in my case i change the state and read this state from my functional component. I belive, what i had done a good explain.

*Sequence of actions: some action => middleware => process action in reducer => change state*

My middleware:

```
import { showPopup } from '../features/popup/popup-slice';

const POPUP_PROPERTIES = {
  loginRejected: {
    message: "LOGIN ERROR",
    styles: {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
  invalidateLoggedInUser: {
    message: "You are logged out from your account",
    styles: {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "#4BE066"
    }
  },
  cardCreateFulfilled: {
    message: "Card set successfully created",
    styles: {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "#01C9F7"
    }
  },
  cardDeleteFulfilled: {
    message: "Card set successfully deleted",
    styles: {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "#4BE066"
    }
  }
}

const PopupMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
  const { type } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case 'auth/login/rejected': {
      dispatch(showPopup(POPUP_PROPERTIES.loginRejected));
      break;
    }
    case 'auth/invalidateLoggedInUser': {
      dispatch(showPopup(POPUP_PROPERTIES.invalidateLoggedInUser));
      break;
    }
    case 'card/create/fulfilled': {
      dispatch(showPopup(POPUP_PROPERTIES.cardCreateFulfilled));
      break;
    }
    case 'card/delete/fulfilled': {
      dispatch(showPopup(POPUP_PROPERTIES.cardDeleteFulfilled));
      break;
    }
    default: break;
  }
  next(action);
}

export default PopupMiddleware;
```

My slice

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// -------------------------------------- Slice --------------------------------------

const initialState = {
  popupEntity: {
    message: null,
    color: null,
  },
  isVisible: false
}

const popupSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'popup',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    showPopup: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        state.popupEntity = action.payload;
        state.isVisible = true;
      }
    },
    hidePopup: {
      reducer(state) {
        state.isVisible = false;
      }
    }
  },
})

export const { showPopup, hidePopup } = popupSlice.actions;

export default popupSlice.reducer;

// -------------------------------------- Selectors --------------------------------------

export const popupStateSelector = state => state.popup;
export const isVisibleSelector = state => state.popup.isVisible;
```

and store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import PopupMiddleware from './middleware/popup.middleware';
import authReducer from './features/auth/auth-slice';
import cardReducer from './features/card/cardSlice';
import popupReducer from './features/popup/popup-slice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    card: cardReducer,
    popup: popupReducer
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(PopupMiddleware)
})

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not. Hooks cant be used outside of components. You should send `isShow` as an action payload when you dispatch the action. Then you would have something like in your middleware

```
...
  if (action.type === 'auth/login/rejected') {
    console.log(action.payload.isShow);
  }
...
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but how can I get the data from my context inside my middleware?

Comment: You cannot do it directly. You should send `isShow` as a parameter to thunk. I see that you are using RTK. Do you use `createAsyncThunk` for async actions then? Do you use `createSlice` for creating reducer. I need these information to write you an example how to get `isShow` to middleware. Update your question with these information and I will update my answer according to that.